# What is the lightest OS I can install on a new computer like XP service pack 2?

Tags: web-browser, operating-system, bootloader, minimization

I cannot figure out how to install my gold XP CD on my late model computer. I keep getting Errors. Why does it not load?

What self-loading and unpatched OS can I boot a new computer with that is light if not lighter than XP?

Note: I like XP for I do not need antivirus or a firewall to go online making browsing extremely fast. The magic codex don't seem to effect or harm this OS. I don't do anything on this CPU I don't want others to see. I haven't got a virus yet but please don't send me one either.

Comment: You should _not_ be using Windows XP if you will be connecting the computer to the internet. Microsoft no longer supports Windows XP, and does not even do security patching for it any longer. XP is _extremely_ vulnerable to being compromised (viruses and other malware). If you are looking for a relatively light-weight operating system and your principal use will be on-line, consider looking into ChromeOS.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I have used the same set up for 10 years now and have not got any viruses? I wander if the people who wrote those viruses has abandoned XP or the more complex ones don't work on XP?

Comment: I've never gotten a virus or other malware either, but that's as much because I keep things updated and don't visit questionable sites as anything else. I don't depend on luck; I make sure I take appropriate precautions - which include patching when available and antimalware.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin after 10 years is not luck.

Comment: What is the error message? Some read error or media error? Furthermore, try to ask for a software recommendation. Also I've experienced some sudden hardness in the mods' behavior, network-wide. I don't know, why is it so. There is a surprisingly cold spring and chaotic weather in the EU, maybe the EU mods got more headaches. Try to not awake the CMs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Ubuntu Linux

Advantages:

- No need for virus filter
- Nice GUI
- Fast
- It will be fast 10 years later, too

Disadvantages:

- It is not a Windows

#### Windows XP

You have likely a media error. So, you need a new CD. Download a Windows XP in iso from anywhere, write it to a new CD, and use your legal license key to activate it.

Advantages

- You got what you want

Disadvantages

- Although it is legal - you have a valid license key -, it might "smell"
- Your RAM is limited to 3GB

#### 64-bit Win2000

Advantages

- Wants yet lesser hardware than XP
- Lesser virus danger, because not even the viruses support it any more

Disadvantages

- It is a fossil. Nothing will work
- Hard to find, yet harder to find it legally

Comment: How do you feel about a OS called Tails?

Comment: @Muze Very good idea! :-)

Comment: @Muze Talis is a Debian-derived distro. I will wait you on the Unix SE ( https://unix.stackexchange.com ), there the community is friendlier as on most hard science sites, and you can count with my help :-)

Comment: +1 Ubuntu. Try Wine for running Windows applications on Linux. It should work well with applications from the Windows XP era. https://www.winehq.org/ You can also look into even lighter version of Ubuntu such as Lubuntu/Xubuntu.

Comment: @user9811991 Thanks. The microsoft ATL (active template library) is widely used by GUI programs, even from that era, and no binary compatible re-implementation exists until now, unfortunately. :-( Other tools are working well.